# Getting error while build Angular google maps(AGM)

Tags: angular, google-maps, angular-google-maps, agm

My angular application is failing to create a prod build. I have used AGM(angular google maps). I had followed every step:

- Installing "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0"
- import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
- AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
  apiKey: '*********************',
  libraries: ["places"]
  }),

  ERROR in Directive ɵb in E:/omni-channel-web/omni-web/node_modules/@agm/core/agm-core.d.ts has no selector, please add it!
  Cannot determine the module for class ɵb in E:/omni-channel-web/omni-web/node_modules/@agm/core/agm-core.d.ts! Add ɵb to the NgModule to fix it.

Can someone please help me, I am breaking my head for 2 days

Comment: Maybe you should start by installing a non-beta version of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Richards was correct I degraded and it worked.

Comment: to which version did you downgrade?